# Why can't we select a position to write from in the terminal window?

Tags: terminal, text-editors, selection

I am on MAC OS X 10.11.6. In the terminal window, it is possible to select text (typically to copy and paste it) but it is impossible to select a position in the text and write from it. It is also impossible to overwrite the selected text.

Is there a good reason for such limitation in the terminal window?

Comment: you tried , arrow up to recall last commands? then highlight edit, or paste

Comment: @TonyStewart Yes, I know arrow up and completion in bash and I am quite used to not being able to select and overwrite on the terminal. I was just curious to know where this limitation comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Historically the terminal is *serial* terminal, which can be used with a printer or typewriter without any video device. The TTY name is also historically: TeleTYpewriter. Read more at wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal

Nowadays you can use `tput` command to write anywhere on screen.